# How to mass update custom dropdown customer attribute to all customers? PHP or SQL

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.2, sql, customer-attribute

I created a new customer attribute (**Drop Down**) and added it to the registration form.

Attribute details found in `eav_attribute` table:

[image]

Everything work as expected, attribute is added to the customer when new account is registered or an existing account was edited and the attribute was added. I can find that in the table `customer_entity_int`:

[image]

Now, I have about 90,000 customers and I need to set a value of this attribute.

**How can I update all the customers custom drop down attribute with the above value? Any method would suit me, PHP or SQL.**

Comment: You can use Collection to set attribute value  for all customers.

Comment: @Sourav thank for tips :) any more advice how to do so? Tutorials or further information? Still struggling... :/

Comment: which M2 version you are using ?

Comment: I am using **Magento ver. 2.2.6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the quick and dirty sql solution:
You need to run this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO customer_entity_int (attribute_id, entity_id, value) 
SELECT 'attribute_id_here' as attribute_id, entity_id, 'default_value' as value from customer_entity;
```

So let's say you have the attribute id 529 for your new attribute and you want to set the value 1370 for all customers for this attribute, jut run:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO customer_entity_int (attribute_id, entity_id, value) 
SELECT 529 as attribute_id, entity_id, 1370 as value from customer_entity;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I leave the question open for further solutions (if any).

Comment: If you want a clean versiin you can put this in an upgrade data script

Answer (score 0):

you can create upgrade Data script and set/change following value in your custom attribute array in your module .
 **'default' => '0',**

Thanks